# Centering a group of images using Masonry

Tags: css, layout, jquery-masonry, centering

I am using Masonry.js on a group of images and trying to center the entire group. I have gotten the group to center when I specify the width of the container grid and set `margin:0 auto`, but would love to center it using a more fluid grid or percentages. (I realize I could use media queries to change the fixed width, but looking for a more seamless option.)

[Here is an example](http://bit.ly/RyxVix) of the code with a fixed width which is centering just fine.

And [here is an example](http://bit.ly/VKBnBP) of the more fluid example that I am trying to center but `margin:0 auto` isn't working.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

you can center a masonry layout using the `isFitWidth` parameter: http://masonry.desandro.com/demos/centered.html

```
$('.container').masonry({ isFitWidth: true });
```

This parameter will set the `width` value on the container, and this will allow you to center the container using CSS:

```
.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: Ah, I missed that in the documentation. Thank you. That worked perfectly.

Comment: Looks like this has been removed in V2. http://masonry.desandro.com/appendix.html#upgrading-from-v2

Comment: Looks like this is back for v3 http://masonry.desandro.com/options.html#isfitwidth